Post a pandas dataframe from Jupyter Notebooks into a Stack Overflow problem
What are the steps to post a Pandas dataframe in a Stack Overflow question?
I found: How to make good reproducible pandas examples.
I followed the instructions and used pd.read_clipboard, but I still had to spend a significant amount of time formatting the table to make it look correct.
I also found: How to display a pandas dataframe on a Stack Overflow question body.
I tried to copy the dataframe from Jupyter and paste it into a Blockquote.   As mentioned, I also ran pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+') in Jupyter to copy it to the clipboard and then pasted it into a Blockquote.
I also tried creating a table and pasting the values in the table.
All of these methods required that I tweak the formatting to make it look properly formatted.
An example dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['Captain', 'Crunch', 72],
     ['Trix', 'Rabbit', 36],
     ['Count', 'Chocula', 41],
     ['Tony', 'Tiger',  54],
     ['Buzz', 'Bee', 28],
     ['Toucan', 'Sam', 38]],
    columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])


Are you specifically asking about a table? Cause "good reproducible pandas examples" says, "include a small example DataFrame, either as runnable code ..."

Are you aware you can just print(df)? It doesn't work with sep=r'\s\s+', but your data doesn't contain any whitespace, so you can just use sep=r'\s+'.

Did you notice that reading in the table with read_clipboard makes the numbers into strings? That's one reason I pointed out the "runnable code" above.

@wjandrea - no, not specifically asking about the table. Any table is fine.

@wjandrea - can you elaborate on the print(df)? I know what prints a df in jupyter notebook / any python IDE. How do I then use that in stack overflow?

For print(df), you just put it in a code block, like in "good reproducible pandas examples" under "copy and pasteable".

Sorry, what do you mean by "Any table is fine"?

@swilson markdown formatted tables are actual not very good to use in pandas questions. I always spend much more time reading markdown data than a simple text version. It's also less compact. Code to set up an example is better. Please keep in mind that generating an example is a one time job, loading the data will be done by multiple contributors. You have to make it easy for them. When a complex logic has to be described I always like the combination of a text table (or even an image) to explain what should be done, and the code to actually load the data unambiguously.

@mozway okay, understood. I was looking for help displaying a pandas df in StackOverflow. The df = pd.DataFrame(...) code I posted in my question should allow any person responding to easily copy and paste it into their preferred IDE and generate a table. I always include that. But I also want to visually show a before and after table in my question as well, which is what took ages to format.

@swilson but why a formatted table? As you can see in my answer a clipboard/printed table is as informative, more compact and easier to copy/paste into a reproducible input. You said that you don't like to "spend a significant amount of time formatting the table", but using a table you get answerers to spend more time reading your data as a reproducible input ;)

.to_markdown()
The easiest method I found was to use print(df.to_markdown()).
This will convert the data into mkd format which can be interpreted by SO. For example with your dataframe, the output is:




first_name
last_name
age




0
Captain
Crunch
72


1
Trix
36
Rabbit


2
Count
Chocula
41


3
Tony
54
Tiger


4
Buzz
28
Bee


5
Toucan
Sam
38



Note you might need to install tabulate module.
.to_dict()
Another option is to use df.head().to_dict('list'), but it might not be the best one for large datasets (will work for minimum reproducible examples though)
{'first_name': ['Captain', 'Trix', 'Count', 'Tony', 'Buzz'], 'last_name': ['Crunch', 36, 'Chocula', 54, 28], 'age': [72, 'Rabbit', 41, 'Tiger', 'Bee']}

Anyone can use this by passing it through pd.DataFrame()

Use .to_dict('list') for a shorter version, since the index is not significant in OP's data.

@wjandrea that's a good point, edited the answer

@SurajShourie I just tried the print(df.to_markdown()) in Jupyter. I copied the table that it generated and pasted it into the questions text box in Stack Overflow and it created a nice table like you are showing above, so worked great.  I did not need to install tabulate, but good to know. Thank you.

Here is how I would share your data example in a post for SO, leaving out the comments I included for assistance here:
#paste the contents of the comma-separated file between two sets of triple ticks
s='''
first_name,last_name,age
Captain,Crunch,72
Trix,36,Rabbit
Count,Chocula,41
Tony,54,Tiger
Buzz,28,Bee
Toucan,Sam,38
'''
#then include in the post the code to make the df instead of 
# assuming people know to use use the table and use read_table
# because this catches any issues, too, because displaying `df` should give starting point
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

(See another example here.)
The nice thing is it lets you draft that by hand or customize it some in a text editor if you want.

Preparation behind-the-scenes
If it was already a dataframe there is no reason to fuss with formatting a table. Let Pandas make it.
To make that I took your dataframe code and did this:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Captain', 'Crunch', 72],
               ['Trix', 36, 'Rabbit'],
               ['Count', 'Chocula', 41],
               ['Tony', 54, 'Tiger'],
               ['Buzz', 28, 'Bee'],
               ['Toucan', 'Sam', 38]],
              columns=['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'])
df.to_csv("df_as_csv.csv", index = False)

Then I pasted the content in the .csv into the s string content in the block above.

I prefer .tsv and found it more human readable; however @wjandrea as pointed out Stack Overflow converts tabs to spaces when rendering posts, so that doesn't work well. Fortunately, comma de-limited can be easily edited and customized by hand to some extent. (And if you really prefer .tsv like me, you can encode it in SO and it will work in Python using \t to function as tabs, like so s='''first_name\tlast_name\tage''' for first line example. You can use Python to do the replacement if you want and it remains hand-editable this way. Curiously, in my hands I cannot find a way to write out with %%writefile` cell magic and get the tabs respected.)

I forgot to say before, you don't actually need to create a CSV file when you can just print it: print(df.to_csv(index=False))

to_dict('tight')
The most reproducible option is to_dict('tight'), this handles data, indexes names, indexes with multiple levels:
data = df.to_dict('tight')
print(data) # this is the output to provide in the question

Then to load the data (here with a more complex example):
data = {
 'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'columns': [('level_0', 'first_name'),
  ('level_0', 'last_name'),
  ('level_0', 'age')],
 'data': [['Captain', 'Crunch', 72],
  ['Trix', 'Rabbit', 36],
  ['Count', 'Chocula', 41],
  ['Tony', 'Tiger', 54],
  ['Buzz', 'Bee', 28],
  ['Toucan', 'Sam', 38]],
 'index_names': ['index'],
 'column_names': [None, None]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='tight')

Output:
         level_0              
      first_name last_name age
index                         
0        Captain    Crunch  72
1           Trix    Rabbit  36
2          Count   Chocula  41
3           Tony     Tiger  54
4           Buzz       Bee  28
5         Toucan       Sam  38

to_clipboard(False)
For small datasets, I like:
df.to_clipboard(False)

Which directly copies a nice padded table:
  first_name last_name  age
0    Captain    Crunch   72
1       Trix    Rabbit   36
2      Count   Chocula   41
3       Tony     Tiger   54
4       Buzz       Bee   28
5     Toucan       Sam   38

This can be read, after copying the block of text, with:
df = pd.from_clipboard()

The poor man's version is:
print(df.to_string())

to_csv()
Another interesting option is to provide the data as CSV. By providing no file name, the CSV output is returned as string:
print(df.to_csv(index=False))

first_name,last_name,age
Captain,Crunch,72
Trix,Rabbit,36
Count,Chocula,41
Tony,Tiger,54
Buzz,Bee,28
Toucan,Sam,38

Then reading with:
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''first_name,last_name,age
Captain,Crunch,72
Trix,Rabbit,36
Count,Chocula,41
Tony,Tiger,54
Buzz,Bee,28
Toucan,Sam,38'''))

